# What are some reasons you cast a char to an int in C++?

Tags: casting, char, int

What are some reasons you would cast a char to an int in C++?

Comment: To find out its ASCII value, do string modifications, scrambling a string for cryptography purposes, etc.

Comment: @NoobCoder: None of those require casting from `char` to `int`.

Answer (score 1):

It rarely makes sense to cast a `char` value to `int`.

First, a bit of terminology.  A *cast* is an explicit conversion, specified via a cast operator, either the C-style `(type)expr` or one of the C++ casts such as `static_cast<type>(expr)`. An *implicit* conversion is not a cast. You'll sometimes see the phrase "implicit cast", but there is no such thing in C++ (or C).

Most arithmetic operators promote their operands if they're of an integer type narrower than `int` or `unsigned int`. For example, in the expression `'0' + 1`, the `char` value of `0` is promoted to `int` before the addition, and the result is of type `int`.

If you want to assign a `char` value to an `int` object, just assign it. The value is implicitly converted, just as it would be if you used a cast.

In most cases, implicit conversions are preferred to casts, partly because they're less error-prone. An implicit conversion specified by the language rules *usually* does the right thing.

There are cases where you really do need to cast a `char` to `int`.  Here's one:

```
char c = 'A';
std::cout << "c = '" << c << "' = " << static_cast<int>(c) << "\n";
```

The overloaded `<<` operator accepts either `char` or `int` (among many other types), so there's no implicit conversion. Without the cast, the same `char` value would be used twice. The output (assuming an ASCII-based character set) is:

```
c = 'A' = 65
```

This is an unusual case because the `<<` operator treats types `char` and `int` very differently. In most contexts, since `char` is already an integer type, it doesn't really matter whether you use a `char` or `int` value.

I can think of one other very obscure possibility. `char` values are *almost* always promoted to `int`. But for an implementation in which plain `char` is unsigned *and* `char` and `int` are the same width, plain `char` is promoted to `unsigned int`. This can only happen if `CHAR_BIT >= 16` and `sizeof (int) == 1`. You're very unlikely to encounter such an implementation. Even on such a system, it usually won't matter whether `char` is promoted to `int` or to `unsigned int`, since either promotion will yield the correct numeric value.

Answer (score 0):

In general, this should rarely ever happen as  it's fairly explicit when to use a char and when to use an int.

However if you were interested in performing arithmetic on a group of chars, you would require more memory to store the overall value, for this reason you could would usually use an int(or any other data type) to store the overall value.

By doing so you would more then likely implicitly cast the chars to the chosen data type.

However you can also explicitly cast these chars before or during calculation(Later versions of C++ take care of this for you though).

This is one such and more common use for the casting of chars.

However in practice, this can usually be avoided as it makers for stronger cleaner code in the long run

Comment: As a side note, a quick way of finding out the place of a letter (`char my_letter`) in the alpabet is `int(my_letter) - int('a') + 1` if it's lowercase and `int(my_letter) - int('A')` if it's uppercase.

Comment: @Ben: The casts are unnecessary, and it's not guaranteed to work (for example it fails on EBCDIC-based systems).

Comment: @KeithThompson: I should have mentioned that this depends on the character encoding. I don't think enough about the vast number of different machines C++ serves. I do like the casts though; they make what's happening clearer to me.

Comment: @KeithThompson: I read your answer, and it makes sense, but I would love an example of when an implicit conversion does the right thing when a cast doesn't. Thanks.

Comment: @Ben: Quite simply, when the cast specifies the wrong type. When you use a cast, you have to specify the target type. It's one more opportunity to make a mistake. It can easily happen when you change the type of a variable, but forget to change the types in the casts in assignments to it.

Comment: @KeithThompson: Fair enough. Thanks